# Basic firebase Component unable to Unmount on view reload

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When the user loads a different view (replaces the user dashboard displaying Firebase info) everything is fine.

But when the user goes back to the user dashboard view, an error is thrown and nothing is rendered on the page.

Error `warning.js?0f60:33 Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.`

Entire component:

```
// register user component

import ...

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const auth = firebase.auth();

class Registration extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            vendorName: '',
            vendorType: '',
            items: [],
            user: null
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    }

    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        // check if user is logged in
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if(user) {
                this.setState({user});
            }
        });
        // retrieve data
        const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('vendors');
        itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
            let items = snapshot.val();
            let newState = [];
            for (let item in items) {
                newState.push({
                    id: item,
                    vendorName: items[item].vendorName,
                    vendorType: items[item].vendorType
                });
            }
            this.setState({
                items: newState
            });
        });
    }
     componentWillUnmount() {
     this.firebase.off();
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `off()` from the database but you should do it on `ref`.

```
this.itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('vendors');
this.itemsRef.on('value', this.someCallback);

//.....

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.itemsRef.off('value', this.someCallback);
}
```

[*From Firebase API for Reference*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off)

> If a callback is not specified, all callbacks for the specified
>   eventType will be removed. Similarly, if no eventType or callback is
>   specified, all callbacks for the **Reference** will be removed.

**Example**

```
var onValueChange = function(dataSnapshot) {  ... };
ref.on('value', onValueChange);
// Sometime later...
ref.off('value', onValueChange);
```